# How to select audio channel in AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayerController on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using the AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayerController to play video files on iOS. How can I switch the audio channel during playback?

I had looked at the API documentation, but could not find any information about audio channel switching (e.g. just enable the left audio channel only).

Appreciate it if you could offer some help to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does the [AudioMixer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app help?

Comment: Is there any updated sample app? Any other location with an example to play one audio channel in AVPlayer?